# Table Views that don't take up the whole screen, within a stack view

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, constraints, tableview

I'm having problems trying to implement a layout for my app. Whenever I use tableviews, it wants to take up as much space as possible. I'm trying to have (from top to bottom) a tableview with two rows, a text field, and a horizontal stack view rooted to the bottom with two buttons. Something like this:

[Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weMRV.png)

My issue is that constraining this has been a bit of a nightmare. At the moment I actually have the view looking just like this, but its hard coded with the top constraint of the tableview being inset by 400. I need a way for this to be flexible, as when I click on the textfield, i'm going to have that adjust to the top of the keyboard, along with the tableview above it.

At the moment I currently have the TableView within a View, which is in a StackView with the textfield and bottom stack view with the buttons. How can I set up the constraints in such a way that the entire stack seems to appear rooted to the bottom of the screen?

I'm sorry if this is a broad question, it's more of a 'How should I go about this' rather than 'How can I do this' kind of question. I should mention I'm doing this programatically too, using SnapKit for the constraints.

Thanks all!

Comment: I also should mention that when I very simply constrain the stack view to the edges, the bottom Buttons and TextField show up perfectly, but the TableView just disappears

Comment: As a general rule, table views are used for repeating, identical (or similar) "rows," most often when there will be more rows than the height of the view so you need scrolling. If you want 2 "rows" + a text field + 2 buttons, it doesn't sound like a table view would be suitable to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by rethinking the whole thing an simplifying. Took the table view out of the stack, put that and the stack view in. Then the problem was my original one, the cells being stuck to the top of the screen and constraining not changing it at all.

So I flipped the table view using

```
tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
```

And doing the same to the two cells to flip them back to normal orientation. Now the view is perfect! Hope this helps anyone in the future

Comment: That sounds like a very awkward (and potentially problematic) way of achieving your layout. If this is similar to what you're after: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKby4.png -- you cn do this easily without a table view or then need to transform anything.